# Mail merge Aspose Word Leding Zero(Lost Zero - Datatable ColumnDatatype = string) C#

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, aspose.words

I use Aspose Word - Mail Merge fill data to Word Template files, Use ADO.NET connect database SQL Server and fill to Datatable, i have checked all my datatable column datatype string, my table in database have nvarchar column type, but mail merger field output lost zero at fist character:

In database:

```
MyTable
(
Order int  
Value nvarchar(200)
)
```

Order = 1, Value = "0123456789"
In datatable result:

```
Order string, Value string
```

Order = 1, Value = "0123456789"

But Mail Merge Output Value :

```
Order = 1, Value = "123456789"
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Aspose.Words are you using?

I tried the following code snippet and it shows the leading zeroes in Word document.

```
string connectionString = @"Server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AsposeTest;User ID=a;Password=a";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "MyTable");

// Load Word document
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(dataDir + "Orders_Template.docx");
doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(ds);
doc.Save(dataDir + "Orders.docx");
Process.Start(dataDir + "Orders.docx");
conn.Close();
```

This is the table design.
[image: Table design]

I put two records in it, with leading zeroes in string column.
[image: Table values]

Template is simple, looks like below.
[image: Word template]

Output includes all rows, with leading zeroes.
[image: Output document]

Comment: Hi Saqib, i use aspose v.7, i use dataview - mytable only one row, about 20 columns, when i get datatable all column i need still leading zero,i convert this datatable to dataview  DataView orderDetailsView = new DataView(dtHoSoQuaMang);
                    doc.MailMerge.Execute(orderDetailsView);, but when output mail merge, lost zero some column i need leading zero

Comment: Please try the latest release. If the leading zeroes appear with the latest version, then there might be an issue with v 7, which was fixed in newer release.

I converted the DataTable to DataView, the leading zeroes do not appear. Using Aspose.Words v 14.6.